# How to store templates in heavy AJAX based web apps

Tags: javascript, ajax, templates

I'm currently working on a concept for a heavy AJAX based web application.

The communication between client and server should be based on JSON, not plain HTML. So I was wondering how to store the templates for the seperate sections and how to get them by the javascript.

For example I have an multiple image uploading form. The user submits and with JSON response I get back title of the album and the src paths of the images. I want to show the complete photo stream from that JSON.

I never built something like I want know, so I'm trying to be prepared before actual programming comes in.

Are there good JS templating libraries? Can I load the templates after the AJAX call or do I need to load every template on the first page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Load the templates on demand. This saves you bandwidth, memory space as well as HTTP requests.
- You can load them as plain HTML or as a bunch of templates, wrapped in JSON.
- Cache them. You should have some sort of caching logic to check first your local cache (localStorage, a JS object on the page etc.) if the template exists. Otherwise, request it from the server.

I suggest using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) for templating. As for storage, I suggest using [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/). For caching logic, build one yourself.